# Text not moving

Tags: animation

I am fairly new to blender and I am trying to make an intro for a video with it but when I try to move the text layer it just reverts back to its old place. How do I get it to stick where I want it to go? This is a downloaded template. All help will be appreciated, Thanks

Comment: Welcome! It is likely related to the presence of keyframed location. Could you post an image of the object's Graph Editor?

Comment: How do I locate the graph editior?

Comment: It's one of the possible [editors](https://www.blender.org/manual/editors/index.html). Open a new frame and change the editor type in the first icon of the menu line. Don't forget to select the right object in the 3D View before taking the screenshot

Comment: Forget it I don't understand this

Comment: Willing or not, you'll have to use it if you are going to change an animation. Here's a gif showing more clearly how you can find it http://imgur.com/CRHXIBV or you can switch to another workspace and find it on the bottom left: http://imgur.com/HUSmjw9